# Como criar um executável a partir de python

Tags: python, windows, .exe, python2exe

Eu estou fazendo um serviço onde tenho que fazer um programa que faça leitura e criação de arquivos com dados numéricos. O problema que tenho é que os computadores em que o programa será utilizado não são acessíveis a mim.

Por causa disso, eu precisava converter meu arquivo `.py` para `.exe`
O programa está pronto em `Python 3.5` e parece que o único programa que pode ajudar a fazer a conversão é o `CX_FREEZE`. Eu usei ele e formei um arquivo...

Tenho 2 problemas:

O arquivo não funciona em computadores que sejam windows 7 (dependendo da versão) , e que não tenham algumas dlls (não são sempre as mesmas)

O Executável está vindo acompanhado de VARIAS pastas com MUITOS arquivos. Isso não me parece viável, queria alguma maneira de "empacotar" os arquivos dentro do meu executável.

O programa não é tão grande, e não usa tantas bibliotecas, Somente OS e DATETIME.

Já tentei utilizar o Pyinstaller e INNO setup, mas nenhum me dá alguma luz.

Gostaria de saber se alguem tem alguma alternativa ou dica que eu possa usar.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os", "datetime"], "excludes": []}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Console"  # para execuções em terminal

setup(name="GetSpecJoin",
      version="0.1",
      description="My GUI application!",
      options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables=[Executable("240117.py", base=base)])
```

Comment: Os arquivos adicionais são as dependências (do Python e de bibliotecas usadas, incluindo talvez o próprio cx_freeze). O envio de múltiplos arquivos não devia ser um impedimento pra vc. Existe [essa pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/112698/2896619) no SOen com respostas que podem te ser úteis. Mas eu não testei, não sei se funciona o que dizem ali. De qualquer forma, se vc realmente quer ter um arquivo só e não quer solicitar a instalação do Python no cliente, talvez seja melhor simplesmente usar outra linguagem (C, por exemplo).

Comment: Eu entendo que essa seria a alternativa mais garantida. Se eu não conseguir resposta em alguns dias terei que fazer isso. O fato é que o cliente não faz questão que o python não seja instalado, ele até aceitou, mas eu acho estranho estar sendo tão complicado de fazer algo tão simples como compilar o arquivo para distribuição.
A ideia de fazer um .exe singular, é que poderá ser pelo menos um pouco portátil.

Comment: Não é que seja complicado. Vc é que não quer enviar as DLLs de dependências junto. E se não rodou no Windows 7 pode ser porque lá faltem algumas DLLs que a sua versão do SO já tem (é comum ocorrer com os [Redistribuíveis do Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=48145), por exemplo, de que algumas bibliotecas do Python dependem). Seria só o caso de instalar, se for essas que estão faltando. De qualquer forma, certamente seria mais fácil ter só um exe, mas aí o mais descomplicado mesmo seria usar uma linguagem apropriada.

Comment: Eu tentei inserir as dll manualmente, mas parece que os arquivos que estão sendo exigidos (api-win-msi-crt-[...].dll) não funcionam na versão do windows 7  instalada (sem sp1) em outras versões com Sp2 o programa funcionou. Ao tentar atualizar o sistema para sp1, o computador fica carregando por horas e não apresenta progresso. até as hotfix da microsoft que deviam corrigir o erro não funcionaram. O problema maior esta sendo as máquinas do cliente com sistema desatualizado, O sistema está "travado" no windows 7 sem nem mesmo sp1.

Comment: É que essas ferramentas de empacotamento simplesmente pegam as DLLs em uso *no seu sistema*. Por isso que não funciona no sistema de destino, se ele for diferente. Pra resolver, só se vc tiver um sistema igual (isto é, na mesma versão do Windows) e empacotar lá também. Enquanto isso, considere também usar o Cython: http://cython.org/ pra converter o seu código Python pra C e depois compilar o código C em um executável. Boa sorte!

Comment: Muito Obrigado! Vou verificar. uma ultima tentativa. :)

Comment: Não sou profissional, mas peço licença para contar o que fiz quando brinquei de criar .exe de programas python. Baixei os arquivos de instalação do Python, se não me engano uma versão minima e coloquei junto com os arquivos do meu programa, empacotei tudo usando o INNO e configurando-o para instalar o Python também, funcionou, pena que só os arquivos do python somam perto dos 100Mb, mas compactados pelo INNO tudo caiu pra mais ou menos 30Mb.

Comment: Me lembrei agora de uma outra forma que usei; Baixei os arquivos do Python, não o instalador mas sim os arquivos e pastas mesmo e deixei junto com meu programa. No INNO configurei para adicionar uma entrada no registro do Windows, para que os arquivos .py(na verdade mudei para uma extensão que não existe, a fim de evitar conflitos) sejam abertos com o executável do Python(pythonw.exe) que está na pasta do python que acompanha meu programa. É meio confuso, mas funcionou aqui.

Comment: O que deu errado com o Pyinstaller? Eu uso python 3.5 e meu pyinstaller funciona perfeitamente. Inclusive, consegue-se criar um arquivo .exe único com todas as dlls inseridas nele com o Pyinstaller, ao invés de uma pasta cheia de arquivos.

Comment: O pyinstaller simplesmente não executa, ele nem abre. eu segui uns 2 tutoriais e deu na mesma

Comment: Tente a biblioteca py2exe 0.9.2.2. Link para download: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/

Comment: Basta você compilar o que o cx_Freeze gera com o IExpress. De uma olhada em minha resposta. Abs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voce pode usar o cx_Freeze.

1. `pip install cx_Freeze`
2. Criar um arquivo chamado setup.py no mesmo diretorio do seu arquivo
   (exemplo teste.py)
3. Dentro do arquivo setup.py você joga o código que vou deixar no
   final da resposta
4. Execute o comando `python setup.py build`
5. Dentro da pasta build vai ter seu executável.

**setup.py**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = None


executables = [Executable("teste.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {

        'packages':packages,
    },

}

setup(
    name = "Nome Executavel",
    options = options,
    version = "1.0",
    description = 'Descricao do seu arquivo',
    executables = executables
)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Sobre o seu problema com diversos arquivos além da executavel**

O cx_Freeze não compila apenas o .exe, porém na própria documentação dele, é indicado o uso do IExpress, para você compactar todo o diretorio gerado pelo cx_Freeze em um unico .EXE

> You can use IExpress to compress the build directory from cx_Freeze into a self-extracting archive: an exe which unpacks your application into a temporary directory and runs it. IExpress is a utility that’s included with Windows, intended for making installers, but it works equally well if you tell it to run the cx_Freeze-built exe after extraction.

Fonte: http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html

Comment: Creio que o problema dele é bem maior do que isto, na verdade falta o AP da pergunta informar qual erro exatamente ocorreu.

Comment: Ok, estou trabalhando em melhorar a resposta, e estudando a fundo tanto o cx_Freeze quanto pynsist e alguns outros. Já edito a resposta.

Comment: Eu encontrei outras formas de dar continuidade ao desenvolvimento sem precisar fazer exatamente isso, mas o conteúdo está muito bom, realizei alguns testes com outros programas que tenho e funcionou bem, acho que quando tentei eu estava fazendo algo errado.